# How to prevent bypassing win.resizable(False, False) while using the -zoomed attribute in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I use win.resizable(False, False) on a window that has the zoomed attribute set to true, the window still can be resized by moving the title bar of the window, or by using the "Super + Down Arrow" shortcut. Is there any way to prevent this?

example code, that can reproduce this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

master.wait_visibility()
master.attributes("-zoomed", True)

master.resizable(False, False)

master.title("This window should not be resizable")

tk.mainloop()
```

Ubuntu 22.04.1

Gnome 42.5

X11

Comment: Have you tried `master.attributes('-fullscreen', True)`? Though that may have some side-effects

Comment: I didn't want the window to be fullscreen, only zoomed to the max size

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a maximized window that could not be resized by doing the following:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
master.resizable(0, 0)  # prevent resizing
master.wait_visibility()  # wait for the window
master.state('zoomed')  # maximize the window


# this guard clause isn't strictly necessary,
# but it's a 'best practice' kind of thing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    master.mainloop()  # run
```

That said, I'm on Windows 10 so YMMV. I hope this helps!

P.S.: I noticed you're calling `tk.mainloop()` instead of `master.mainloop()`, which may or may not be a problem (at the very least, it's unorthodox) - just a heads-up!

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately on Linux the only accepted values for .state are "normal", "iconic" and "withdrawn". Replacing the line with 'master.attributes("-zoomed", True)' does not help. But I've noticed that adding a label to the window rules out about 50 % of cases, where the window size changes. But I didn't help myself much, because now its random .